# jdbc metadata DEBUG RUN result difference

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

I have DAO class that gets table names that corresponds to specific pattern.

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class TableMetadataDAO {

        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource ds;

        public List<ColumnMetadata> load() {
            List<ColumnMetadata> list = jdbcTemplate.execute(new ConnectionCallback<List<ColumnMetadata>>() {

            public List<ColumnMetadata> doInConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException {
               List<ColumnMetadata> list = new ArrayList<>();
               DatabaseMetaData metaData = con.getMetaData();
               ResultSet rs = metaData.getColumns("", "", "tmp_%", "");
               while (rs.next()) {
                   ColumnMetadata cmd = new ColumnMetadata();
                   cmd.setTableName(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
                  list.add(cmd);
               }
               rs.close();
               return list;
           }

           });
       }   
    }
```

I'm invoking the load method from a spring-boot test:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-it.properties")
    public class TableMetadataControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private TableMetadataDAO tmd;


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Test
        public void tmpTables() throws Exception {

            List<ColumnMetadata> list = tmd.load();
        }
    }
```

Now I'm putting a breakpoint on `List<ColumnMetadata> list = tmd.load();` and do step over. The result I'm getting is correct, meet my expectations. However when I'm doing step into and traversing DAO method line by line, I'm getting an exception on `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.` on method invocation `rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")`.
I'm really confused and have no idea what to do next in order to find what is the cause of such a strange behaviour. Could you give some advices what steps could be possibly done to find the root cause.

**EDITED:**
Hikari configuration log

```
2018-11-05 14:38:46.842 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2018-11-05 14:38:46.917 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2018-11-05 14:38:46.923 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
2018-11-05 14:38:46.928 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2018-11-05 14:38:46.932 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2018-11-05 14:38:46.937 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2018-11-05 14:38:46.942 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2018-11-05 14:38:46.946 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2018-11-05 14:38:46.951 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2018-11-05 14:38:46.955 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2018-11-05 14:38:46.967 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2018-11-05 14:38:46.973 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
2018-11-05 14:38:46.978 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2018-11-05 14:38:46.983 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2018-11-05 14:38:46.987 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................600000
2018-11-05 14:38:46.995 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailFast..........true
2018-11-05 14:38:47.002 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2018-11-05 14:38:47.010 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2018-11-05 14:38:47.017 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
2018-11-05 14:38:47.022 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/docker
2018-11-05 14:38:47.027 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........0
2018-11-05 14:38:47.032 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................1800000
2018-11-05 14:38:47.036 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................10
2018-11-05 14:38:47.041 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2018-11-05 14:38:47.046 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsTrackerFactory@1dd74143
2018-11-05 14:38:47.050 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................10
2018-11-05 14:38:47.054 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password........................<masked>
2018-11-05 14:38:47.059 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
2018-11-05 14:38:47.065 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2018-11-05 14:38:47.071 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2018-11-05 14:38:47.076 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2018-11-05 14:38:47.081 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutorService........internal
2018-11-05 14:38:47.085 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2018-11-05 14:38:47.089 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2018-11-05 14:38:47.093 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2018-11-05 14:38:47.098 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"docker"
2018-11-05 14:38:47.102 DEBUG 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
2018-11-05 14:38:47.105  INFO 32256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

Comment: Not related to your issue but you are leaking a connection here. You obtain a connection yourself and never close it. The same applies to the `ResultSet`. Regarding the error, could be that it takes too long for you to step over/into and the connection gets closed.

Comment: Thanks. Edited. I've tried different 'debug situations'. Once I traversed all lines without stopping, later made a delay in one second for each line. The result for fast and slow case is identical. I'm not sure in hicaricp configuration. May be it has settings that affects debugging?

Comment: One of the issues I see is that you are using the datasource and obtaining a connection outside of a transaction (basically your `@Transactional` is useless). Instead of using the `DataSource` use the `JdbcTemplate` and a `ConnectionCallback` (saves you quite some code).

Comment: Thanks one more time. Edited. The problem still remains. I noted that when don't put break point inside inside doInConnection() all works well, however when I touch result set method I either get the described exception or the result contains less rows than it is necessary.

Comment: Then I don't have another clue, could be something in the postgres driver.